# Date Time gives error after hosting

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datetime

I have a column in MSSQL DB Which has stored following date:

> 2016-06-10 10:55:00.000

I am calling this column on frontend using datareader, then parsing it to a specific format and then comparing with other date to find timestamp.
Issue is when I run it from Visual Studio, it works fine. but when I upload it on live server, I get the following exception:

> 6/10/2016 10:55:00 AM ::: d1 ::: :: System.FormatException: String was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime. at
>   System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style) at
>   login.btn_login_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Following is my code:

```
tst = b.dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + " ::: d1 ::: ";
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(b.dr.GetValue(1).ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
tst = "d2";
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
tst = "d3";
TimeSpan ts = d2.Subtract(d1);
tst = "d4";
```

I have also tried:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(b.dr.GetValue(1).ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Still it doesnot work on live server.
Also tried:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(b.dr.GetValue(1).ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

But no wonders.
Being a live server, it needs to be completely independent of the system culture and should work same along all the date time formats opted by the clients in their operating systems.

Note: On development end, I am using MSSQL R2 2008 Express while live server uses MSSQL 2012.

Comment: Is this happening on the first line of code: tst = b.dr.GetValue(1).ToString() + " ::: d1 ::: ";? I'm also assuming 'tst' is a string?

Comment: The date in the exception text looks like it only has one digit for the day, is separated by `/`, and includes `AM/PM`. The format you've specified expects 2 day digits and `-` separators.

Comment: The error message states that the string '6/10/2016 10:55:00 AM ::: d1 :::' is not recognised as a valid DateTime. The only time you create the string with '::: d1 :::' in it is on the first line of code you've shown us. Is 'tst' of type DateTime?

Comment: Be aware, that **whenever you *see* a date** you do not see the value but its **string representation**. The format you **see** in MS-SQL, as well as the format you see elsewhere is a culture depeding conversion. Whenever you want to send data *cross-border* you should make sure, that you are using an independant format. Best was ISO8601, in your case this was  `2016-06-10T10:55:00.000` (if `06` means June!!).

Comment: I just see, that you are trying to parse `6/10/2016` with `dd-MM-yyyy`. This is - at least - a heavy sign for *dm/md* mix-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date in the database is stored in a date format, then you may be able to do as follows:

```
DateTime d1 = b.dr.GetDateTime(1).Date;
DateTime d2 = System.DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan ts = d2.Subtract(d1);
```

Edit:

Provided that the field is stored in the database in a date format such as date, datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime, etc., the SqlDataReader.GetDateTime() method will fetch and convert the value to a .Net DateTime value. It is usually more convenient to manipulate date values when they are represented as these specialized date data types.

The problem with date strings is that sometimes these can have multiple interpretations. The specialized date formats, however, each has a specific and well defined interpretation. You may, however, again run into format issues if you try to convert date/time values to or from string representations. As long as you can avoid such conversions, all will be well irrespective of the date time settings in server.

If the field in the database doesn't have a time component (If the database datatype is DATE and not DATETIME), you can omit the .Date part of the first line and do as follows:

```
DateTime d1 = b.dr.GetDateTime(1);
DateTime d2 = System.DateTime.Today;
TimeSpan ts = d2.Subtract(d1);
```

Comment: You're obviously on the right track here, but you haven't explained it at all well. You should let the OP know why this works.

Comment: Worked perfect ... But how and why??? And will it work irrespective of the date time settings in server?

Answer (score 0):

What is you DB field type?
Assuming it is a `datetime`. It is unclear why do you do `ToString()` on it to parse string right away. `ParseExact` does exactly that. Format you are looking for should match exactly. It won't match you formats with "::::..." added to string. Also, `ToString()` uses current culture which might be different on the server so again you requested format in `ParseExact` might not match.